# iOS code signing trouble while archiving application

Tags: ios, code-signing

I trying to make a new version of my application to ad-hoc distribution.
But, unfortunately, I have a strange error:

> Provisioning profile 'WL Moon' specifies the Application Identifier
>   'asap.WeatherApp' which doesn't match the current setting
>   'asap.WeatherApp'

I revoked profile, and created it again, but nothing changed.

With development profile I haven't any problems, and I can run application on my testing iPhone.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

I cleaned all provisioning profiles on my iPhone, from XCode Organizer. Also I restarted XCode.

I think, problem happened because I changed distribution certificate (we are added push notifications to application), and on my device was two different certificates with the same name.